# Bitbucket code changes don't get rejected?

Tags: github, bitbucket

I really need your help as a new programmer. I have uploaded my project to bitbucket and invited my friend with admin privileges, whenever he opens the project via Clion and makes some changes I don't see those being reflected on my own side instantly (or even after a day). How can we fix this?

This is what he did:

- Open invitation link
- Click on Accept Invitation
- Click on Clone
- Open Clion then VSC and paste the link he got from clone
- Make edits to code which I don't see